# I could not find the disable_l2cache in my config file then How to disable it?

Tags: raspbian, software-development

I have recently purchased Raspberry PI model B board. i could not find the **disable_l2cache** in my config file.can anyone please tell me how to make sure that cache has been disabled.Also i would like to lock only protion of ARM L2 cache in Raspberry PI. Any help inthis also would be appreciated.

Comment: …Why do you want to this?

Comment: I want this because i need to compare the performance of Raspberry PI by enabling and disabling cache.Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The config file is even optional itself, so just add the disable_l2cache option as you wish.

```
disable_l2cache=0
```

Actually this is the default value, so if you want to ENABLE ARM's access to L2 cache, you need not to do anything. But for how to make sure it is disabled, sorry I don't know either.